# Co-authoring in Excel, OWA

Tags: 2010, excel, office-web-apps

After installing Office Web application in my SharePoint server 2010, we are unable to co-authorise with Excel. But this co-authorise function works with Word and PPT. Is there any setting we need to check?

Answer (score 0):

Co-authoring in Excel and SP 2010 only works in the web editor.

Comment: You mean open the excel in SP using "Edit in browser". If that is the case, its not working that way.